# Convert a column of datetimes to epoch in Python

Tags: python, datetime, pandas, epoch

I'm currently having an issue with Python. I have a Pandas DataFrame and one of the columns is a string with a date.
The format is :

> "%Y-%m-%d %H:%m:00.000". For example : "2011-04-24 01:30:00.000"

I need to convert the entire column to integers. I tried to run this code, but it is extremely slow and I have a few million rows.

```
for i in range(calls.shape[0]):
    calls['dateint'][i] = int(time.mktime(time.strptime(calls.DATE[i], "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:00.000")))
```

Do you guys know how to convert the whole column to epoch time?

Answer (score 57, accepted):

convert the string to a `datetime` using `to_datetime` and then subtract datetime 1970-1-1 and call `dt.total_seconds()`:

```
In [2]:
import pandas as pd
import datetime as dt
df = pd.DataFrame({'date':['2011-04-24 01:30:00.000']})
df

Out[2]:
                      date
0  2011-04-24 01:30:00.000

In [3]:
df['date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['date'])
df

Out[3]:
                 date
0 2011-04-24 01:30:00

In [6]:    
(df['date'] - dt.datetime(1970,1,1)).dt.total_seconds()

Out[6]:
0    1303608600
Name: date, dtype: float64
```

You can see that converting this value back yields the same time:

```
In [8]:
pd.to_datetime(1303608600, unit='s')

Out[8]:
Timestamp('2011-04-24 01:30:00')
```

So you can either add a new column or overwrite:

```
In [9]:
df['epoch'] = (df['date'] - dt.datetime(1970,1,1)).dt.total_seconds()
df

Out[9]:
                 date       epoch
0 2011-04-24 01:30:00  1303608600
```

**EDIT**

better method as suggested by @Jeff:

```
In [3]:
df['date'].astype('int64')//1e9

Out[3]:
0    1303608600
Name: date, dtype: float64

In [4]:
%timeit (df['date'] - dt.datetime(1970,1,1)).dt.total_seconds()
%timeit df['date'].astype('int64')//1e9

100 loops, best of 3: 1.72 ms per loop
1000 loops, best of 3: 275 µs per loop
```

You can also see that it is significantly faster

Comment: Be aware that `astype('int64')//1e9` transforms `NaT` (datetime missings) to -9223372037.0 and instead the total_seconds correctly returns nan, so, even if more cumbersome, it's definitely safer.

Answer (score 24):

I know this is old but I believe the correct (and cleanest) way is the single line below:

```
calls['DATE'].apply(lambda x: x.timestamp())
```

This assumes `calls['DATE']` is a `datetime64[ns]` type. If not, convert it with:

```
pd.to_datetime(calls['DATE'], format="%Y-%m-%d %H:%m:00.000")
```

**Explanation**

To get the epoch value (in seconds) of a `pd.Timestamp`, use:

```
pd.Timestamp('20200101').timestamp()
```

This should give you `1577836800.0`. You can cast to an `int` if you want. The reason it is a float is because any subsecond time will be in the decimal part.

You can also get the raw epoch value (in nanoseconds):

```
pd.Timestamp('20200101').value
```

Gives 1577836800000000000 which is the epoch of the date above. The `.value` attribute is the number of nanoseconds since epoch so  divide by 1e6 to get to milliseconds. Divide by 1e9 if you want epoch in seconds as the first call.

Answer (score 11):

From the [Pandas documentation](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/timeseries.html#from-timestamps-to-epoch) on working with time series data:

> We subtract the epoch (midnight at January 1, 1970 UTC) and then floor divide by the “unit” (1 ms).

```
# generate some timestamps
stamps = pd.date_range('2012-10-08 18:15:05', periods=4, freq='D')

# convert it to milliseconds from epoch
(stamps - pd.Timestamp("1970-01-01")) // pd.Timedelta('1ms')
```

This will give the epoch time in milliseconds.

Answer (score 2):

To expand on the answer of s5s, I think the code can be further generalised to cater for missing data (represented by pd.NaT, for example). Tested on Pandas 1.2.4, won't work on Pandas < 1.0.

```
calls['DATE'].apply(lambda x: x.timestamp() if not pd.isna(x) else pd.NA).astype('Int64')
```

Some comments:

- pd.isna() will catch pd.NaT
- The lambda expression translates pd.NaT to pd.NA, which will be the new representation of missing data
- Finally, the output from the lambda expression will be a mix of integers and pd.NA, thus we need a Pandas ExtensionDtype such as Int64 to handle that

Sample output:

```
0            <NA>
1            <NA>
2            <NA>
3            <NA>
4            <NA>
          ...
865    1619136000
866    1619136000
          ...
Name: DATE, Length: 870, dtype: Int64
```

Answer (score 1):

If the aim is to simply convert datetime into numbers, then you can view a datetime column as int64. Since the default resolution is nanoseconds, to convert into seconds, the int64 result must be divided by 10^9.

```py
df = pd.DataFrame({'date': pd.date_range('2020','2021', 3)})
df['as_int64'] = df['date'].view('int64')
df['seconds_since_epoch'] = df['date'].view('int64') // 10**9
```

[image: result]

Another way is, after subtracting the Unix epoch, convert the dtype to `'timedelta64[s]'` (note the `[s]`) to specify that you want the difference in seconds or `'timedelta[ms]'` to specify that it should be in milliseconds, etc.

```py
df['epoch'] = df['date'].sub(pd.Timestamp('1970-01-01')).astype('timedelta64[s]')
```

Answer (score 0):

As of writing these lines, you can do that very easily with pandas (tested with version 1.5.2). Here is a working example with a DataFrame filled with strings representing timestamps.

```
df = pd.DataFrame(data=["2022-08-01T22:45:12", "2022-08-01T22:46:12", "2022-08-01T22:47:12"], columns=["time"])
df['time'].apply(lambda x: pd.Timestamp(x).timestamp())
```

Note that the function timestamp() returns a POSIX timestamp as float. If you do not have milliseconds with the timestamps, you can cast the result as integer.

```
df['time'].apply(lambda x: int(pd.Timestamp(x).timestamp()))
```