# Convert a column of yyyy-mm-dd datetimes to linux time epoch in Python

Tags: python, pandas, datetime

In python 3.6.0 and pandas 0.20.0

there is a date column yyyy-mm-dd

```
date
2017-08-16
2017-08-17
2017-08-18
```

There is the same question here

[Convert a column of datetimes to epoch in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35630098/convert-a-column-of-datetimes-to-epoch-in-python)

But sadly none of the solutions in the post works

```
df['date']=df['date'].astype('int64')//1e9

ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: '2017-08-16'


df['date']=(df['date'] - dt.datetime(1970,1,1)).dt.total_seconds()

NameError: name 'dt' is not defined
```

Any thoughts?  Thank you.

Comment: Errors say: Your column is a string and you didn't import correctly.

Comment: This is why it's important to make a minimal reproducible example.

Comment: Second error it's probably because you forgot to import the correct module (i.e. `import datetime as dt` or rename dt with datetime if you have `import datetime`)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try with `pd.DateTimeIndex` and multiply of 1000 is to make it milliseconds ( you can ignore multiplication if you want in seconds)

```
  df['Date'] = (pd.DatetimeIndex(df['Date']).astype(np.int64) // 10**9) * 1000

print(df)

         Date
1502841600000
1502928000000
1503014400000
```

Answer (score 1):

Instead of doing it manually, you can just convert it to `datetime` and use `timestamp()`

Something like this.

```
from datetime import datetime

s = '2017-08-16'
epoch = datetime.strptime(s, "%Y-%m-%d").timestamp()
print(epoch)
# Output -- 1502821800.0
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
from datetime import datetime as dt

# String for the date
s = '2017-08-16'

#Convert string to datetime
s_dt = dt.strptime(s, '%Y-%m-%d')

#Initialize epoch
epoch = dt.utcfromtimestamp(0)

#Get your difference from epoch in ms
linux_time = (s_dt - dt.utcfromtimestamp(0)).total_seconds()*1000

#Your output
linux_time
1502841600000.0
```

This is a code for a single date object. You could create a function and use lambda to apply it to the pandas column.

Hope this helps.